# Replacing a term in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I am Currently Learning phyton and I got to know about Variables and how to use them, They are great.

But my Question is What if I am give a pre written code and was asked to replace a specific term out of it ? How do I replace all of them, Cuz using Variable we can only replace the term which has code(for ex Charenter_name = Name in the story This is possible only when we are adding it while writing the code) But how to replace them if everything was written already and we have to replace it.

I know to find it we just have to say CTRL+F but what can we use to replace everything at once ?

Sorry if my question was not clear

Thanks in Advance.

I tried re-searching online and didn't really understand the results,
I would need a layman level of explaining in the regards.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please clarify by what you mean.  Did you mean using Python to replace code with some other code inside a pre-written code or did you mean how to use your editor to replace code?

Comment: If I've understood you correctly, this is not actually a Python question (even though you are editing Python code) and is more to do with the IDE or editor you are using. What program are you using to write and edit your Python code? (e.g. IDLE, notepad++, Pycharm, Spyder etc.)

Comment: Thanks for response am using PyCharm and my questions is do we have an option that is similar to Excel (Find and replace text press Ctrl+H) in pytho .

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can use variable ,Which basically will help you replace specific data from your code. there are no restrictions to it.
`Link` https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5WSPeLEvZ9c

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).